# Running .NET 5 Api under Kestrel from Visual Studio 2019 ignores launchSettings.json applicationUrl setting

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

We are having an "only on my machine" issue that nobody can figure out.

We have a .NET 5 Api that we run under Kestrel for development purposes. On every other dev VM running the API in Visual Studio picks up on the values in `launchSettings.json` and launches on the correct ports. However on a the VM in question, it only launches on the default 5000/5001 ports.

This is the entry for the `launchSettings.json` file.

```
"profiles": {
    "My.Api": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "environmentVariables": {
            "LogStorageAccountConnectionString": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        },
        "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7001;http://localhost:7000"
    }
}
```

I know there is a way to tell `dotnet run` to explicitly ignore `launchSettings.json` but could not find a setting in Visual Studio that would trigger that behavior.

We also thought it might be a permissions issue on the folder because they were a bit weird so we cloned our repo into a new folder and set up the Api again to be run locally. It still ran on 5000/5001.

The lot of us are stumped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem also running `.NET 5` API (and also a `Blazor` project) under Kestrel with Visual Studio. For me however it came suddenly - I was running the project successfully for a couple of weeks and then one day it started refusing to honour `launchSettings.json` and keep running on default `5000/5001`.

I have solved this by upgrading Visual Studio from 16.8.3 to 16.8.4. However since I did not have problems initially with 16.8.3 I suspect the problem is not about Visual Studio version. I think that my original installation got corrupted somehow and the upgrade just fixed the corruption.

BTW my `launchSetting.json` were honoured when I ran the project from command line using dotnet run. I could also use a workaround by setting the port in `Program.cs`

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseUrls("https://localhost:6000");
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this issue too with both .NET 5 and .NET 6 in Visual Studio 2022, and the only thing that worked was to set the (apparently undocumented) variable `Urls` in the `environmentVariables` section of `launchSettings.json`. In other words:

```json
"profiles": {
    "My.Api": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "environmentVariables": {
            "LogStorageAccountConnectionString": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
            "Urls": "https://localhost:7001;http://localhost:7000"
        }
    }
}
```

Sadly VS's "Launch Profiles" dialog does not pick up this value nor allow you to set it, but editing `launchSettings.json` manually isn't too much of a pain.

---

UPDATE

We discovered this issue was due to our use of Autofac and the following in Startup.cs's `ConfigureContainer` method:

```
builder.RegisterInstance(configuration.ConfigurationRoot)
    .As<IConfiguration>().SingleInstance();
```

where `configuration` is our custom configuration provider and `ConfigurationRoot` is of type `IConfigurationRoot`.

We're not quite sure why this line was added, so we removed it and everything seems to work correctly, including passing the `--urls` argument.